# MySQL - password theoretically changed... only when logging in from server

Tags: mysql, docker, mysql-workbench

I have changed my MySQL root password using this command:

```
mysqladmin -u root -p'123' password '321'
```

Now, the new password works on the server, to proove that I have used this command:

```
mysql -u root -p'321' -e 'show databases;'
```

Works perfectly. But when I want to connect to the database using the new password from MySQL Workbench, or configure the spring-database.xml to use the new password - it is failing... but - I still can log in through MySQL Workbench using the old password... What kind of magic it is? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this command to set password.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
```

and restart the mysql server.

Comment: Can you paste the log messages , it's weird to work with cli but not with applications